# Did Charlie Hebdo ever publish any cartoon satirizing Judaism?

Tags: media, judaism

Did Charlie Hebdo ever publish any cartoon satirizing Judaism?

If **Yes**, was there any protest from the Jewish community?

If **No**, why not? What is the reason (they have published enough cartoons satirizing Jesus and Mohammad. Why would they spare Judaism)?

Comment: How is this a question about politics?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, whether it is a question about politics or not, depends on your perspective. Coz, Charlie Hebdo is a political magazine.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Yes**, they did make fun of Judaism alone from time to time, but not nearly as much as Christianity. [A good example of what you could find in it](http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/archives/2013/03/08/26598304.html) (*translation: title "circumcise all males the eighth following their birth"; commentator: "why do we not wait for him to be old enough to understand?"; rabbi: "we have to enjoy our superiority while we still have it!"*).

[Here](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2015/02/24/non-charlie-hebdo-n-est-pas-obsede-par-l-islam_4582419_3232.html) is an article (in French, but English speakers can get the gist) including statistics on their front covers. The overwhelming majority is about French politicians, and their favourite religious target is the Catholic church. Usually, a rabbi is present when they decide to make fun of religions altogether.

There was legal action from LICRA ([International League against Racism and Antisemitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_League_against_Racism_and_Anti-Semitism)) in 2008 against one of their journalists on [antisemitism charges](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/aug/03/france.pressandpublishing). It was not against the paper itself, though, but about some things the journalist said on the radio (more [here](https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/IMG/pdf/jugement-licra-sine.pdf)).

The religions they make fun of are kind of correlated with the [religious profile of France](http://www.indexmundi.com/france/religions.html). Since they mostly tackle current affairs, one can also assume they make more fun of the noisiest people. The Jewish community in France, even though it is [the largest in Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_population_by_country), is still only around one percent of the general population (I say "around" since religious profiling is forbidden in France, all you can get are rough estimates).

If you want to know more about who Charlie Hebdo pissed off, their website has a special [court](https://charliehebdo.fr/proces/) section.

Comment: A newspiece from The Guardian explaining what happened in 2008: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/aug/03/france.pressandpublishing

Comment: "... ... but not nearly as much as Christianity" --- why?

Comment: @anonymous ask why to the authors. They will probably answer you it is because there are more catholics than jews in France and they expose themselves to being mocked more often.

Comment: @Gilles, why are you editing this answer?

Comment: @user5751924 "ask why to the authors". Well, almost all of them are dead now. Great answer though.

Comment: @anonymous he edited it to clear up the grammar

Comment: @anonymous [Editing other people's questions and answers is acceptable and common on this network](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/editing), particularly to tidy up formatting and grammar, or correct obvious mistakes. You can see what changes were made by clicking the "edited X ago" link, which takes you [to the full list of revisions for that particular post](http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/15759/revisions).

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the answer given and found this article in English to help which is well translated.

However you might find it a [bit shocking](http://forward.com/schmooze/212244/when-charlie-hebdo-lampooned-jews-too/).

As a side answer, I strongly disagree with the comments made about targeting specific religions because we are prominently catholic. That is wrong! 
I am French and an atheist. France is a laicised country which means all religions are accepted but none can be prominent.

Charlie Hebdo is a paper that represents freedom of speech in its purest form.
There are many papers like it. The only difference is that they use caricatures which is an instant message for a wider audience not necessarily capable to understand it!

Comment: What I meant by the comment is that if they were living in Israël, they might have done more covers on judaism. But the fight against gay wedding and "sausage party" (the movie) in France is done by catholics. I am French and atheist too, and indeed, France is very poorly religious : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreligion_in_France . This correlates what I have experienced, many people will say they are catholic since they are baptised while not caring at all. But comparing different polls is another topic.

Comment: Agreed. I understand your comment. Religion has been a very complicated problem in France(or anywhere really) but it has been exacerbated by freedom of speech and social media reaching audiences not necessarily equipped to understand...bit patronising, I know but true, I think.